# What is time complexity of this recursive function?

Tags: java, time

```
public static int[] index(int input[],int x,int i){   
    if (i==0) {
        if (input[i]==x)
            return new int[] {0};
        else
            return new int[] {};
    }
    int[] c = index(input, x, i-1);
    if (input[i] == x) {
        int len = c.length + 1;
        int[] a = new int[len];
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j <= c.length - 1; j++)
            a[j] = c[j];
        a[j] = i; // j++ 
        return a;
    }
    return c;
}
```

What is time complexity of this recursive function which returns all indices of occurrence of an element x in an input array?

Comment: Amount of function invocations is directly proportional to `i`, and since the function doesn't contain internal cycles the complexity is linear,
O(n)

Comment: @edwgiz there is actually a for loop inside so that makes it O(n^2) .

Comment: yeah, sorry, missed index array copying. The worst case when the whole `input` contains only `x` is O(n^2)